# How to use when condition to loop in Ansible

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, ansible

I need ansible to examine all the remote IP addresses, and if the remote system is in a particular subnet, then copy a file to the remote system. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to make ansible loop over a list or dictionary in the `when` clause.

This throws a syntax error `Error was expected string or buffer`, because `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` is a list or dictionary, not a string:

```
- name: auto.direct 10g
  copy: src=auto.direct.10g dest=/etc/auto.direct owner=root group=root mode=0644
  when: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | search("192.168.17")
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd want something like this:

```
- name: auto.direct 10g
  copy: src=auto.direct.10g dest=/etc/auto.direct owner=root group=root mode=0644
  when: ansible_{{ item }}['ipv4']['address'].find("192.168.17") != -1
  with_items: ansible_interfaces
```

The `ansible_interfaces` variable is just a list of all the network devices (`eth0`, `eth1`, `lo`, etc) that exist on the hosts.  The above task will loop over each of those devices and then look for variable names like `ansible_eth0`, `ansible_lo`, etc.  It gets the ipv4 address string out of each of those variables, and just does a find (since the string is just a python string).

FYI, this can be very helpful in understanding/troubleshooting/debugging this sort of thing:

```
- name: debug
  debug: var=ansible_eth0 (or 'ansible_eth0['ipv4']', etc)
```

Or if you want to do something move involved like with the logic I used above:

```
- debug: var=ansible_{{ item }}['ipv4']['address']
  when: ansible_{{ item }}['ipv4']['address'].find('10.') != -1
  with_items: ansible_interfaces
```